# How to reduce server wait time

Tags: performance, iis

I am trying to optimize my site's speed and I'm using the great tool at pingdom.com. Right now, over 64.45% of the time it takes to load the page is "Wait" time as shown in the screenshot below.My Hosting is on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition. What can I do to reduce this? Also, how typical is this figure? Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a client waiting for response on the socket, so you have to consider tcp latency in there.

Comment: Don't you have some kind of documentation from pingdom.com available where should be described what exactly this value mean?